# Google sheets - Show data from old version by date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where I keep records of student enrollment. I want to compare today's numbers with the previous year's same day's numbers.
So I want to take the data from version history and compare the same days after one year.
Is there any way to bring data from version history?

Answer (score 0):

steps

1. Make a copy (new sheet) of your current sheet.
2. Use version history, find the dates and reverse to those dates. Make another copy.
3. Reverse the master sheet to current state.